# 1048 error even when value is given to the columns mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert

i have a table named staff

```
CREATE TABLE `staff` (
`idstaff` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`lname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`gender` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`bloodgroup` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
`dob` date NOT NULL,
`mobile_no` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`qualification` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`department` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`designation` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`joindate` date NOT NULL,
`retiredate` date NOT NULL,
`refname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`mobile` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`relationship` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idstaff`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1003 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

then this is my stored procedure for insert data

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_staffs`(
IN fnme varchar(45),
IN lnme varchar(45),
IN address varchar(45),
IN gender varchar(45),
IN bloodgroup varchar(3),
IN dateob date,
IN mobilenum varchar(45),
IN email varchar(45),
IN edu varchar(45),
IN department varchar(45),
IN designation varchar(45),
IN joindate date,
IN retiredate date,
IN refname varchar(45),
IN refnum varchar(45),
IN rel varchar(45))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO staff
(`fname`,
`lname`,
`address`,
`gender`,
`bloodgroup`,
`dob`,
`mobile_no`,
`email`,
`qualification`,
`department`,
`designation`,
`joindate`,
`retiredate`,
`refname`,
`mobile`,
`relationship`)
VALUES
(@fnme,
@lnme,
@address,
@gender,
@bloodgroup,
@dateob,
@mobilenum,
@email,
@edu,
@department,
@designation,
@joindate,
@retiredate,
@refname,
@refnum,
@rel
);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and when i call the procedure

```
call insert_staffs('gore','asdf','asdf','m','ab','1980/03/29','safd','asdf','asdf',
'asdf','asdf','2000/01/04','2030/01/03','sdaf','sdaf','sadf');
```

it throws the 1048 error("column 'fname cannnot be null'")

but when i pass the same value in simple insert statement

```
INSERT INTO `hospitalmgmt`.`staff`
(`fname`,
`lname`,
`address`,
`gender`,
`bloodgroup`,
`dob`,
`mobile_no`,
`email`,
`qualification`,
`department`,
`designation`,
`joindate`,
`retiredate`,
`refname`,
`mobile`,
`relationship`)
VALUES
(
'gore','asdf','asdf','m','ab','1980/03/29','safd','asdf',
'asdf','asdf','asdf','2000/01/04','2030/01/03','sdaf','sdaf','sadf');
```

it is inserted.

So , what is wrong with my stored procedure ... how can i pass values through stored procedure? 
Please Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the parameter without `@` sign inside your procedure. I mean your insert statement inside procedure should be like

```
INSERT INTO staff
(`fname`,
`lname`,
`address`,
)
    VALUES
    (fnme,
    lnme,
    address,
    );
```